# Get label of svg element according to its id

Tags: c#, xml, svg, xml-parsing

I want to get label of svg element. I wrote a console application and thougt svg file as xml. I am trying to get labels according to id of element. When i wrote code below, i got all ids but i cant get label with that row. How can i access the label? An example of element is;

```
<rect
       style="fill:#cccccc"
       id="21"
       width="35.823246"
       height="35.823246"
       x="299.87155"
       y="65.999405"
       class="seatObj"
       inkscape:label="A22" />
```

And codes are;

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"seatChart-01.svg");
            XmlNodeList elementList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("rect");
            string[] labels = new string[elementList.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < elementList.Count; i++)
            {   
                int id = int.Parse(elementList[i].Attributes["id"].Value);
                labels[id] = elementList[i].Attributes["inkspace:label"].Value;             
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(labels[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elementList[i].Attributes["inkspace:label"].Value
```

should be

```
elementList[i].Attributes["label", "http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"].Value
```

I'm assuming that the namespace is that of the inkscape drawing program here. To confirm that look for something on the root element that looks like this...

```
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
```

Comment: If i try to get element with class property, how can i provide it?